# Texture big problem

Tags: texturing, uv

For the last hour I tryed texturing my pack of chips, but something always goes wrong.

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuC9X.png

What did I do wrong?

1. Make frame and mark seams
2. Unwrap all faces inside.
3. Apply texture
4. Nothing fit

Or just select and unwarp, I tried all the ways I found in Youtube,

If any one could check it out, I would be very grateful

blend file https://megawrzuta.pl/download/a6163c8500ae92021a2231ea045108dd.html

And graphic file (don't ask, very early prototype of rat food with my friend in foreground:)

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E50cj.jpg

Greeting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First af all apply rotation and scale to your model (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).

Mark as seams all edges surrounding the 5 faces of your pack; Then <kbd>U</kbd> Unwrap.

Enable the "UV Squares" addon, then select the front faces and choose the function "Snap to axis (X or Y)". This will preserve the proportions of your edges while setting up a rectangle UV Grid. Then scale the UV to fit your image.

[image]