# How to properly "uncurve" those UV wrapping projections?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I can't figure out how to "uncurve" those UV wrapping projections. Any idea?

[image: Uncurve UV wrapping projections]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the UV squares addon, it does exactly what you're looking for.

Related: [Texture big problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72377/texture-big-problem/72382#72382)

Comment: This add-on solved my issue. Thanks Josh.

Comment: This is essentially a link only answer. Please provide sufficient information here in this answer or just post it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

As @josh sugggested me, I used the [UVSquares](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/UV/Uv_Squares) add-on in order to solve my issue.

[image: UVSquares add-on]